# Как сделать, что бы открывались не все скрытые формы с комментариями, а именно одна которую выбрал?

Tags: php, jquery

Есть стена сообщений
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

под каждым сообщением есть кнопка комментарии, при нажатии добавляется поле для комментариев. Когда открываю 1 то открываются все. Как сделать открытие именно выбранного го сообщения ?вот так делал открытие
`$(".comment_post").click(function () {
        $(".comment").slideToggle("fast");
    });`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
<script>
    $(".comment_post").click(function () {
        $(".comment").slideToggle("fast");
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="design/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<?php foreach ($data['messages'] as $message){?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item active"><?php echo $message->created ?></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $message->text ?></li>
                    <span class="comment_post">Комментировать</span>
                    <form method="POST" class="comment">
                        <textarea rows="1" cols="75"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" name="send_comment" value="Отправить">
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Вместо картинок лучше покажите HTML структуру, это полезнее..

Comment: все, добавил код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы раскрыть только тот блок, в котором нажали кнопку, нужно сначала определить общего родителя для кнопки и скрытого блоки, и уже в нем искать блок `.comment`:

```js
$(".comment_post").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.list-group').find(".comment").slideToggle("fast"); // находим общего родителя (в данном случае .list-group), а уже в нем ищем .comment
});
```

```css
.comment {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item active">
        Дата
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Текст
      </li>
      <span class="comment_post">Комментировать</span>
      <form method="POST" class="comment">
        <textarea rows="1" cols="75"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="send_comment" value="Отправить">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item active">
        Дата
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Текст
      </li>
      <span class="comment_post">Комментировать</span>
      <form method="POST" class="comment">
        <textarea rows="1" cols="75"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="send_comment" value="Отправить">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item active">
        Дата
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Текст
      </li>
      <span class="comment_post">Комментировать</span>
      <form method="POST" class="comment">
        <textarea rows="1" cols="75"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="send_comment" value="Отправить">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item active">
        Дата
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Текст
      </li>
      <span class="comment_post">Комментировать</span>
      <form method="POST" class="comment">
        <textarea rows="1" cols="75"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="send_comment" value="Отправить">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое